# Example of $3$-dimensional Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

I have a question on $3$-dimensional Lie algebra $L$ over ${\bf C}$
(cf. Erdmann and Wildon's book)

Assume that $$ L=(x,y,z),\ L'=(y,z)$$

Then the book states that there exits two kinds of $L$ :

(1) $$ [y,z]=0,\ {\rm ad}_x = \left(
                                \begin{array}{ccc}
                                  0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                  0 & 1 & 0 \\
                                  0 & 0 & \mu \\
                                \end{array}
                              \right)
$$ wrt $\{ x,y,z\}$. Here is an example $$ y=  \left(
                                \begin{array}{ccc}
                                  0 & 0 & 1\\
                                  0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                  0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                \end{array}
                              \right),\ z=\left(
                                \begin{array}{ccc}
                                  0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                  0 & 0 & \mu \\
                                  0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                \end{array}
                              \right),\ x= \left(
                                \begin{array}{ccc}
                                  0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                  0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                  0 & 0 & -1 \\
                                \end{array}
                              \right)
$$

(2) $$ [y,z]=0,\ {\rm ad}_x = \left(
                                \begin{array}{ccc}
                                  0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                  0 & 1 & 1 \\
                                  0 & 0 & 1 \\
                                \end{array}
                              \right)
$$ wrt $\{ x,y,z\}$.

${\bf Question :}$ Give me an example of this kind.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, what is $\mu$?

Comment: It is a complex number.